# How to convert []byte slice into JSON GOLANG

Tags: json, go

Very new to Golang and i am having a hard time in converting a byte slice into a valid JSON
bytt := []byte(`{"tracks":{"track":[{"name":"Yellow","duration":"276","artist":{"name":"coldplay"},{"name":"red","duration":"345","artist":{"name":"somename"}}}]}`)

`fmt.Println(bytt)` returns
`[123,34,45,32 ....]` like this
i can do `string(bytt)` that gives me a readable string which i cant use and loop through.

learning marshaling unmarshalling with a single dimensional byte is what i have encountered till date as learning. Please help me to understands the basics as i come from PHP JAVASCRIPT background multidimensional array concept is not similar to this

Comment: https://go.dev/blog/json

Comment: use  `var jsonData map[string]interface{}
 err := json.Unmarshal(bytt, &jsonData)
 if err != nil {
  fmt.Println("Error:", err)
  return
 }

 // Now jsonData is a map containing the parsed JSON structure
 fmt.Println(jsonData)`

Answer (score -1):

use `fmt.Printf("data = %s", bytt)` then can print "{"tracks":{"track":[{"name":"Yellow","duration":"276","artist":{"name":"coldplay"},{"name":"red","duration":"345","artist":{"name":"somename"}}}]}"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).